# jQuery Dropzone Accepted Files DWG not allowed?

Tags: jquery, mime-types, dropzone

I'm trying to limit the accepted file type to only ".dwg" extensions, here's my code and Dropzone is accepting all file types. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or how I can fix this?

Using Dropzone 5.2 and Jquery 3.3.1

```
$("#dwgFiles").dropzone({
        url: urluploadDwg,
        paramName: "file", 
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop files to upload <span>or CLICK</span>',
        maxFilesize: 15,
        acceptedFiles: '.dwg',
        success: function (result) {
            var res = response;
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
            console.log("Successful upload!");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log("error: " + response.toString());
            alert("error: " + response.toString());
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add the MIME type.

```
acceptedFiles: 'image/*,image/vnd.dwg,.dwg'
```

it could also be `application/acad`

Comment: So I've tried all of your attempts. I  think one of them may be right. I say *I think* because after all of them failing, I changed my "acceptedFiles" parameter to one of Dropzone's examples:  `acceptedFiles: 'image/*,application/pdf,.psd'` and STILL Windows Explorer shows all file types. Something else is wrong...